# Is there any way to use the props outside the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I need to pass a duck to my component to do a search on redux. How can I pass this duck as "props"?

My Screen

```
import React from 'react'
const MyScreen: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {

    return (
        <Component
            navigation={props.navigation}
            duck={MyDuck}
        />
    );
}
```

My Component

```
import React from 'react'
    const MyComponent: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
    const {duck} = props;
    
        return (
            <View/>
        );
    }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispacth) {
    return {
        //I need to use the prop here in this place
        register: duck.mapDispatchToProps(dispacth),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the props using the second argument of [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) which is `ownProps` -- the props passed to the component.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
  const duck = ownProps.duck;
...
```

or just

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, {duck}) {
```

But the question that you are asking is not going to make this code work. The `duck` prop is a component `MyDuck` which **does not have a `mapDispatchToProps` property.**  `mapDispatchToProps` is an argument to the `connect` higher-order component.  It is not a property.

I don't understand what you are trying to do here but you will need to approach it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

There is a optional mergeProps callback available as third argument in connect which follows the below format

```
(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) =>
    ({ ...stateProps, ...dispatchProps, ...ownProps })
```

stateProps - are all the props from mapToState callback
dispatchProps -  are all the props from mapDispatchToProps callback
ownProps - are all the props that are passed down to the component like <Button foo={'bar'} />

you will be able to access the desired duck prop in the ownProps argument

reference - https://www.emgoto.com/redux-access-props-mapdispatchtoprops/